# Microsoft Teams starts up on login even though I have removed it from the startup applications list in GNOME Tweaks

Tags: linux, gnome, startup

I'm having trouble disabling Teams as a startup application. I'm running Fedora 35 with GNOME as my desktop environment.
I got to GNOME Tweaks and remove Teams from the list of startup applications. But whenever I restart my computer and login, Teams is there to greet me. I go back to Tweaks and see that Teams has been added to the startup applications list. What can be the reason for this? But more importantly, how can I stop Teams from starting up on login?

Comment: You can do a `ps` to see the parent process, that might help you identify the startup sequence.

Comment: How exactly do I go about doing that? Do I just type **ps** into the terminal?

Comment: If you find an answer please let me know. I cannot wait until I can uninstall this app. Until then, I hope to stop it from starting on startup.

Comment: @mikael you can type: "ps aux | grep teams" to see the process. Then run kill XXXX, with whatever pid (should be the second column).

Comment: @TheBrewmaster turns out that there is a simple solution: open Teams -> click on the three dot icon on the tool bar -> click on _Settings_  -> _General_ -> uncheck _Auto-start application_ and voila, no more Teams on startup.

Comment: seems too easy 

Answer (score 0):

To stop Teams from starting up on login:

1. open Teams
2. click on the three dot icon on the tool bar
3. click on Settings
4. click on General
5. uncheck Auto-start application